# Is it possible to develop using Xcode and Adobe Flex at the same time?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ipad, charts, adobe

I've been looking for interactive chart library for iOS but it seems like there's not so many options out there. I've tried CorePlot and two other commercial library but even though the licensing were very expensive they're not quite what I'm looking for or close to some of the charts found in [Microstrategy](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microstrategy-mobile-for-ipad/id382821025?mt=8) or Roambi app like the on below ...

[image]

Then I found an article about Adobe Flex with a few [sample](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/mobile-trader-application.html) applications build using Adobe Flex that can run on iOS. Pretty interesting technology but I'm mostly interested with its chart. Is it possible to create a library using Adobe Flex(with chart views) and import the library into Xcode?

Comment: I've asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947369/is-it-possible-to-include-pre-compiled-objective-c-libraries-into-flash-cross-co and have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to combine binaries from Xcode and binaries from Flash or vice versa, unfortunately.

Comment: Good question! For which framework did you finally decided, Eric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create applications with Flex/Flash for iOS using AIR. And there is also a great opportunity exists to import native iOS libraries created with Xcode to the Flex (find some samples [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)). So you just need to look for appropriate charts functionality implemented with flex/flash and try to launch it under the iOS to see whether you'll be satisfied with performance or not.

Answer (score 0):

Flex = Flash, and iOS != Flash. Clearly, Xcode wouldn't allow it. You could try compiling a bundle from Adobe's cross compiler tool, if that is indeed possible, and use class-dump to access it. Perhaps.

> Adobe Flex 4.5 and 4.6 have introduced ANE (Adobe Native Extensions). This allows extending the Adobe AIR runtime ( there is runtime for IPhone, IPad, Adroid, Blackberry 10, ) using native code.
>
> For IPhone you can write a static library compiled as a .a file and import that into your Flex Iphone project and compile as ANE.
>
> Flex also has some native things like vibration, camera etc support, but if you want to do anything nifty with it, just write native.
>
> Compared to Titanium, PhoneGap, KendoUI etc - Adobe Flex 4.6 really stands out. One thing that you must be aware of that Adobe Air runtime needs to be on the device. From Adobe Flex 4.6 onwards, you can actually bundle the air runtime with your app - it is called the captive runtime.